# Left Outer Join and Counts in Oracle

Tags: oracle

My instructor has the the questions below
7)  A museum requests the first and last names of all archeologists, as well as the number of locations where they have found Tyrannosaurus Rex dinosaurs. Note that some archeologists have not found any dinosaurs, and some have not found any Tyrannosaurus Rex dinosaurs, but still should be included in the list.

The statement i wrote below only shows me the archeologists that have discovered a trex. Can anyone help with how i can include all information from the question?

```
 SELECT ARCHEOLOGIST.FIRST_NAME, ARCHEOLOGIST.LAST_NAME,DINOSAUR.DINO_NAME, LOCATION.LOCATION_ID,
  COUNT(LOCATION.LOCATION_ID)AS TOTAL_LOCATIONS
FROM ARCHEOLOGIST
LEFT OUTER JOIN DISCOVERY ON DISCOVERY.ARCH_ID = ARCHEOLOGIST.ARCH_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATION ON LOCATION.LOCATION_ID = DISCOVERY.LOCATION_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN DINOSAUR ON DISCOVERY.DINO_ID = DINOSAUR.DINO_ID
WHERE (DISCOVERY.DINO_ID = 123) 
group by ARCHEOLOGIST.FIRST_NAME, ARCHEOLOGIST.LAST_NAME, DINOSAUR.DINO_NAME, LOCATION.LOCATION_ID;

CREATE TABLE DINOSAUR
(DINO_ID NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
DINO_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
DIET_TYPE VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
COST NUMBER(10));

CREATE TABLE LOCATION
(LOCATION_ID VARCHAR2(2) PRIMARY KEY,
LOCATION_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
STATE_NAME VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE ARCHEOLOGIST
(ARCH_ID VARCHAR2(3) PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE DISCOVERY
(DISC_ID VARCHAR2(3) PRIMARY KEY,
DISC_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
DINO_ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
ARCH_ID VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
LOCATION_ID VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL);

ALTER TABLE DISCOVERY
ADD CONSTRAINT DINO_ID
FOREIGN KEY (DINO_ID)
REFERENCES DINOSAUR(DINO_ID);

ALTER TABLE DISCOVERY
ADD CONSTRAINT ARCH_ID
FOREIGN KEY (ARCH_ID)
REFERENCES ARCHEOLOGIST(ARCH_ID);

ALTER TABLE DISCOVERY
ADD CONSTRAINT LOCATION_ID
FOREIGN KEY (LOCATION_ID)
REFERENCES LOCATION(LOCATION_ID);

INSERT INTO DINOSAUR
(DINO_ID, DINO_NAME, DIET_TYPE, COST)
VALUES
(123,'TYRANNOSAURUS REX','CARNIVORE',100000);

INSERT INTO DINOSAUR
(DINO_ID, DINO_NAME, DIET_TYPE, COST)
VALUES
(234,'TYRANNOSAURUS REX','CARNIVORE',500000);

INSERT INTO DINOSAUR
(DINO_ID, DINO_NAME, DIET_TYPE, COST)
VALUES
(345,'TYRANNOSAURUS REX','HERBIVORE',250000);

INSERT INTO DINOSAUR
(DINO_ID, DINO_NAME, DIET_TYPE)
VALUES
(456,'TYRANNOSAURUS REX','HERBIVORE');

INSERT INTO DINOSAUR
(DINO_ID, DINO_NAME, DIET_TYPE, COST)
VALUES
(567,'TYRANNOSAURUS REX','HERBIVORE',500000);

INSERT INTO DINOSAUR
(DINO_ID, DINO_NAME, DIET_TYPE, COST)
VALUES
(789,'TYRANNOSAURUS REX','CARNIVORE',750000);

INSERT INTO LOCATION
(LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_NAME, STATE_NAME)
VALUES
('A1','BLACK HILLS','SOUTH DAKOTA');

INSERT INTO LOCATION
(LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_NAME, STATE_NAME)
VALUES
('B2','LOS ANGELES','CALIFORNIA');

INSERT INTO LOCATION
(LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_NAME, STATE_NAME)
VALUES
('C3','GRAND CANYON','ARIZONA');

INSERT INTO LOCATION
(LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_NAME, STATE_NAME)
VALUES
('D4','TAMPA','FLORIDA');

INSERT INTO LOCATION
(LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_NAME, STATE_NAME)
VALUES
('E5','ROME','NEW YORK');

INSERT INTO LOCATION
(LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_NAME, STATE_NAME)
VALUES
('F6','CALGARY','CANADA');

INSERT INTO LOCATION
(LOCATION_ID, LOCATION_NAME, STATE_NAME)
VALUES
('G7','MILWAUKEE','WISCONSIN');

INSERT INTO ARCHEOLOGIST
(ARCH_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME)
VALUES
('ABC','ERNEST','HEMINGWAY');

INSERT INTO ARCHEOLOGIST
(ARCH_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME)
VALUES
('DEF','AYN','RAND');

INSERT INTO ARCHEOLOGIST
(ARCH_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME)
VALUES
('GHI','GRETA','GARBO');

INSERT INTO ARCHEOLOGIST
(ARCH_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME)
VALUES
('JKL','FRED','ASTAIRE');

INSERT INTO ARCHEOLOGIST
(ARCH_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME)
VALUES
('MNO','GINGER','ROGERS');

INSERT INTO DISCOVERY
(DISC_ID, DISC_DATE, DINO_ID, ARCH_ID, LOCATION_ID)
VALUES
('Z12',TO_DATE('12/12/2010','MM/DD/YYYY'),123,'ABC','A1');

INSERT INTO DISCOVERY
(DISC_ID, DISC_DATE, DINO_ID, ARCH_ID, LOCATION_ID)
VALUES
('A58',TO_DATE('12/15/2011','MM/DD/YYYY'),123,'ABC','C3');

INSERT INTO DISCOVERY
(DISC_ID, DISC_DATE, DINO_ID, ARCH_ID, LOCATION_ID)
VALUES
('R47',TO_DATE('07/18/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'),345,'MNO','A1');

INSERT INTO DISCOVERY
(DISC_ID, DISC_DATE, DINO_ID, ARCH_ID, LOCATION_ID)
VALUES
('F21',TO_DATE('06/15/2009','MM/DD/YYYY'),456,'JKL','E5');

INSERT INTO DISCOVERY
(DISC_ID, DISC_DATE, DINO_ID, ARCH_ID, LOCATION_ID)
VALUES
('B65',TO_DATE('05/10/2011','MM/DD/YYYY'),456,'ABC','F6');

INSERT INTO DISCOVERY
(DISC_ID, DISC_DATE, DINO_ID, ARCH_ID, LOCATION_ID)
VALUES
('O99',TO_DATE('08/20/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'),234,'MNO','G7');

INSERT INTO DISCOVERY
(DISC_ID, DISC_DATE, DINO_ID, ARCH_ID, LOCATION_ID)
VALUES
('H71',TO_DATE('05/10/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'),567,'ABC','F6');

INSERT INTO DISCOVERY
(DISC_ID, DISC_DATE, DINO_ID, ARCH_ID, LOCATION_ID)
VALUES
('B34',TO_DATE('07/25/2010','MM/DD/YYYY'),123,'DEF','D4');

INSERT INTO DISCOVERY
(DISC_ID, DISC_DATE, DINO_ID, ARCH_ID, LOCATION_ID)
VALUES
('K81',TO_DATE('08/01/2016','MM/DD/YYYY'),567,'MNO','B2');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags, and include the definitions of the tables involved and statements to populate those tables with data. Or post a link to a database testing environment such as [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4) or [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2) with your tables set up and populated. Without that kind of information there's not really too much anyone here can do. Thanks.

Comment: @Erica: As Bob has asked, it'd be beneficial to see the statements for table creation and data insertion. You apparently have those, as you are already executing some queries against the DB.

Comment: Sorry, I am brand new at this and just learning. I added everything i used to create my tables and insert my data. Hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: hahaha It should say Database Specialist - Student. Thank you for that though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that there is no need for a outer join to fulfill the requirements of the question.  The only fields that they have asked for are First and last names and a count.... no need to output the dino name or location, this means you can use the below to get the list you need.

```
SELECT ARC.FIRST_NAME, ARC.LAST_NAME, (select count(distinct loc.LOCATION_ID) 
                                                      from DISCOVERY dis
                                                      inner join LOCATION loc on dis.location_id = loc.location_id
                                                      inner join DINOSAUR din on din.DINO_ID = dis.DINO_ID
                                                      where ARC.ARCH_ID = dis.ARCH_ID
                                                      and DIS.DINO_ID = 123) as loc_disc_TREX
FROM ARCHEOLOGIST ARC;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This makes a lot more sense than what i had been taught so far and it worked!

Comment: No problem.  If the solution worked for you please accept the answer so that others can see that it is solved.

Comment: Why the `DISTINCT` in your scalar subquery?  With no `GROUP BY`, there should only be one row.

Comment: The question asked 'number of locations where they have found Tyrannosaurus Rex ' NOT how may TRex they had found so we need the distinct location.... If a person had found 2 TRex at the same location it should only count as 1... Could proabably been represented better as select  count(distinct loc.LOCATION_ID)

Comment: Actually edited answer as it should be select count(distinct loc.location_id).... didn't test this edge case, just chucked a distinct in and got it in the wrong place.  Thanks for the pickup @MatthewMcPeak

Comment: Thank you, everyone! As someone who is just learning, I greatly appreciate it. This site is such an amazing resource.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ds.location_id) AS locations_with_t_rex_found
  FROM archeologist a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN discovery ds
    ON ds.arch_id = a.arch_id
   AND ds.dino_id = 123
 GROUP BY a.first_name, a.last_name
 ORDER BY locations_with_t_rex_found DESC, a.first_name, a.last_name
```

This results in:

```
FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | LOCATIONS_WITH_T_REX_FOUND
-----------+-----------+---------------------------
Ernest     | Hemingway |                          2
Ayn        | Rand      |                          1
Fred       | Astaire   |                          0
Ginger     | Rogers    |                          0
Greta      | Garbo     |                          0
```

Look at this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=380f1a0d94c11ce5f7616e339deffd05), to see it in action. (I've adjusted your sample data, as you seem to be naming all your dinosaur entries 'TYRANNOSAURUS REX' in your inserts, while previously you've posted something more diverse.)

The key difference (apart from skipping some tables), as compared to the original query from the question, is to specify the dinosaur species filtering condition in the left join match criteria, instead in the overall `WHERE` clause (to just limit the joined table, not the whole result).

This approach, as compared to the [correlated subquery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54622572/5853770) from [@Shaun Peterson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2833401), allows you also to easily get additional "statistics", e.g. to also return count of actual discoveries (e.g. to cover for multiple discoveries in one location), you would just add e.g. `COUNT(ds.disc_id)` to the column expressions list.

As for skipping tables:
You do not need to reference the `LOCATION` table, as you do not need location names, and calculating distinct location count can be based on `LOCATION_ID` in `DISCOVERY` table. You also do not need the `DINOSAUR` table in the query, unless you want to filter for T-Rex based on dinosaur name, instead of dinosaur ID.
To add the tables back, you'd need to be careful on how you join. This should work:

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ds.location_id) AS locations_with_t_rex_found
  FROM archeologist a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (discovery ds
             INNER JOIN dinosaur dn ON ds.dino_id = dn.dino_id)
    ON ds.arch_id = a.arch_id
   AND dn.dino_name = 'Tyrannosaurus Rex'
 GROUP BY a.first_name, a.last_name
 ORDER BY locations_with_t_rex_found DESC, a.first_name, a.last_name
```